# Print Value to File

Tags: ocaml

i was not able to print an a value (float) to a file with the OCaml lenguage.
How can i do?
If you know how, can you show me a little example?

Thank you advance and have a good day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Printf.fprintf` allows direction to an `out_channel`, in your case a file. Reasonably, you'd open the file for writing first, and pass around that channel.

```
Printf.fprintf (open_out "file.txt") "Float Value of %f" 1.0
```

Comment: There is also `Printf.kfprintf : (out_chan -> 'a) -> format` that comes in handy quite often, unfortunately, it does not support the `%a` custom, user-defined printer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print the *textual* representation of a `float` to a file, perhaps the simplest thing to do is:

```
output_string outf (string_of_float myfloat)
```

If you want to print the float to the console, you can use

```
print_string (string_of_float myfloat)
```

Of course, `Printf.printf` can also do that and more, so it is worth knowing it.

If you want to output the *binary* representation of a `float`, things are more complicated. Since a `float` value is represented as an [IEEE 754 double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double-precision_64_bit), it is 8 bytes long which can be written in different orders depending on the platform. In the case of *little-endian order*, as is normal in X86, you can use the following:

```
let output_float_le otch fv =
  let bits = ref (Int64.bits_of_float fv) in
  for i = 0 to 7 do
    let byte = Int64.to_int (Int64.logand !bits 0xffL) in
    bits := Int64.shift_right_logical !bits 8;
    output_byte otch byte
  done
```

The `float` value so written can be read back with the following:

```
let input_float_le inch =
  let bits = ref 0L in
  for i = 0 to 7 do
    let byte = input_byte inch in
    bits := Int64.logor !bits (Int64.shift_left (Int64.of_int byte) (8 * i))
  done;
  Int64.float_of_bits !bits
```

This has the advantage of being a very compact way to exactly preserve `float`s in a file, that is, what you write will be read back exactly as it originally was. For example, I did this in the interactive top-level:

```
# let otch = open_out_bin "Desktop/foo.bin" ;;
val otch : out_channel = <abstr>
# output_float_le otch 0.5 ;;
- : unit = ()
# output_float_le otch 1.5 ;;
- : unit = ()
# output_float_le otch (1. /. 3.) ;;
- : unit = ()
# close_out otch ;;
- : unit = ()
# let inch = open_in_bin "Desktop/foo.bin" ;;
val inch : in_channel = <abstr>
# input_float_le inch ;;
- : float = 0.5
# input_float_le inch ;;
- : float = 1.5
# input_float_le inch ;;
- : float = 0.333333333333333315
# close_in inch ;;
- : unit = ()
```

and as you can see I got back exactly what I put in the file. The disadvantage of this form of writing floats to files is that the result is not human-readable (indeed, the file is *binary* by definition) and you lose the possibility to interoperate with other programs, like Excel for instance, which in general exchange data in human-readable textual form (CSV, XML, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try printf?

> let a = 4.0
>
> printf "my float value: %f" a

Cf the [doc inria](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-308/libref/Printf.html) and don't forget to open the module